# LP modeling with two binary variables with XPRESS

Tags: variables, binary

I am trying to solve a LP, which is a facility location problem.
The task asks me to deduct 10.000$ iff the optimal model results in having less than 3 Distribution Centers open (y1,y2,y3,y4).

The objective function looks like this: **min z = Σ(fi*yi) + ΣΣ(cij*xij) + ΣΣ(xij*bi) - Σqi*10.000**

- fi: fixed costs
- yi: binary variable; yi = 1 - DC is open; yi = 0 - DC is closed
- cij: transportation costs from DC i to customer j
- xij: quantity shipped from DC i to customer j
- bi: variable warehouse costs at DC i
- qi: binary variable; bi = 1 - IT Cost reduction yes; bi = 0 - no IT cost reduction

Now I need to introduce a logical constraint for having the "if..then..." thingy in it. I want to express the following dependence as a constraint in xpress:

- if Σyi ≤ 2 ; then Σqi  = 1 → IT cost reduction
- if Σyi > 2 ; then Σqi  = 0 → no IT cost reduction

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by introducing the following constraints:

- 3 ≤ Σyi + 2q ≤ 4